# Can two different distributions have the same value of mean, variance, skewness, and kurtosis?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, skewness, kurtosis

Assuming that you have two discrete population distributions.

Can they have identical values of mean ,variance, skewness and kurtosis while being different in shape visually ?

Do these four values act like a fingerprint of any distribution?

Comment: Yes. In fact, one can construct two different discrete distributions with all moments equal, yet do not agree in distribution. Also check out this question: [Two random variables with same moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790858/two-random-variables-with-same-moments).

Comment: You may already know this but when in such a situation where you have some statistics which reduce the space of possible distributions but do not identify a single distribution then you should generally choose the probability distribution with the [maximum entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_entropy_probability_distribution).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Xi'an's answer proved (or at least hinted a proof) that there are different distributions with the same mean, variance, skewness and kurtosis. I just want to show an example of three visually distinct discrete distributions with the same moments (mean=skewness=0, variance=1 and kurtosis=2):

[image: Three discrete samples with the same moments]

The code to generate them is:

```
library(moments)

n <- 1e6

x <- c(-sqrt(2), 0, +sqrt(2))
p <- c(1,2,1)
mostra1 <- sample(x, size=n, prob=p, replace=TRUE)

x <- c(-1.4629338416371, -0.350630832572269, 0.350630832573386, 1.46293384163564)
p <- c(1, 1.3, 1.3, 1)
mostra2 <- sample(x, size=n, prob=p, replace=TRUE)

x <- c(-1.5049621442915, -0.457635862316285, 0.457635862316022, 1.50496214429192)
p <- c(1, 1.6, 1.6, 1)
mostra3 <- sample(x, size=n, prob=p, replace=TRUE)

mostra <- rbind(data.frame(x=mostra1, grup="a"),
                data.frame(x=mostra2, grup="b"),
                data.frame(x=mostra3, grup="c"))
aggregate(x~grup, data=mostra, mean)
aggregate(x~grup, data=mostra, var)
aggregate(x~grup, data=mostra, skewness)
aggregate(x~grup, data=mostra, kurtosis)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mostra)+
  geom_histogram(aes(x, fill=grup), bins=100)
```

Comment: This is really good mate. The question I wanted to is that are the shapes significantly different ? can you plot the shape of the distributions well ?

Comment: I did. These are discrete distributions and the bar diagram above shows the shape of the three distributions (one different color each). Probability is zero for all values except for those where a bar is. The same exercise could be done with a continuous distribution - for example, plotting a case of Xi'an's answer.

Answer (score 15):

Take a mixture of two Normal distributions with density
$$f(x|\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\omega)=
\frac{\omega}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}\exp\{-(x-\mu_1)^2/2\sigma_1^2\}+
\frac{1-\omega}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}\exp\{-(x-\mu_2)^2/2\sigma_2^2\}$$
This distribution has five parameters constrained by four equations
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[X]&=\omega\mu_1+(1-\omega)\mu_2\\
\text{var}(X)&=\omega\sigma_1^2+(1-\omega)\sigma_2^2+\omega(\mu_1-\mathbb{E}[X])^2+(1-\omega)(\mu_2-\mathbb{E}[X])^2\\
\mathbb{E}[X^3]&=\ldots\\
\mathbb{E}[X^4]&=\ldots
\end{align*}
 Assuming these equations are compatible, there is therefore an infinite number of solutions $(\mu_1,\mu_2,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\omega)$.

Comment: How come 4 equations ? Wont there be 4 equations to be solved for each distribution ? Assuming 4 eq for mean , variance , skewness and kurtosis - And is this applicable to discrete distributions as well ?

Comment: You can use a discrete version of this mixture distribution, with no difference in the conclusion.